# Create a Custom Toolbar programmatically on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app with some behavior. As an upgrade I'm going to add a Toolbar to the app. I know, I can do it putting de XML on each activity. But I want to  create a Layout XML for the action Bar and inflate on each activity on the OnCreate method.

This way I think I can add the bar whenever I need it without touching the XML,and maybe make the code more efficient:

Assumptions:

- I have a XML with a layout with tag "< Toolbar >"
- The app has the    noActionBar theme

This is an extract of OnCreate()

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar barra =(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.barra_herramientas,null);
        LinearLayout layout_actividad = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenedor_principal);
        layout_actividad.addView(barra);
```

Comment: Actually I found that i was getting de Incorrect ID, so had a null object.\n But i want to know if this is a good practice.